# "Pocket Wi-Fi" to DD-Wrt in Wifi Client-Router mode, to PowerBeam M2 Client to PowerBeam M2 AP

Tags: router, wireless-access-point

Good day all, I have set up a network for my family in the Philippines because they have a mountain blocking their house from receiving cell phone internet signal.

So down the street about 1 kilometer at a relatives house we have a Pocket Wi-fi that gets great signal from the cell tower and works fine, connected to it is a dd-wrt router in client mode (not client bridge mode) so it connect great to the pocket wifi and acts as a router giving out 192.168.3.x addresses and routes no problem. If you plug a laptop into it you get online just fine.

Then also at the same location i have an ubiquity PBE-M2-400 in Client-(bridge mode) mode (station mode as they call it). you can see this from the laptop plugged in to the dd-wrt also no problem.

Then at my in-laws house i have another PBE-M2-400 in AP-bridge mode. From the relatives house you can also see it fine and verify a great connection between the two dishes, i can log into either ones config page. From my inlaws house however they are having trouble obtaining an IP when they bring the laptop and connect to it there. Is there something wrong with my setup? Can i not channel the dd-wrt router through the PBE client and have it hit the AP? there is a reason i want it this way and not to use the dish at the relatives house in AP mode so please if you would not suggest me to do that.

is there a difference in the way data gets passed from a client to an AP than data from an AP going to clients? are broadcast packets blocked or something? should i enable wds? Thank you.

Comment: Bridge Mode
• The device forwards all network management and
data packets from one network interface to the other
without any intelligent routing. For simple applications,
this provides an efficient and fully transparent network
solution.
• There is no network segmentation, and the broadcast
domain is the same. Bridge mode does not block
any broadcast or multicast traffic. You can configure
additional firewall settings for Layer 2 packet filtering
and access control.
• WLAN and LAN interfaces belong to the same network
segment and share the same IP address space. They
form...

Comment: http://dl.ubnt.com/guides/airOS/airOS_UG.pdf said the above so i think my config should work fine